# How to use jmeter SOAP/XML-RPC Request sampler?

Tags: java, xml, soap, jmeter

I have a requirement to send XML file as a part of the request using Jmeter.
 
Through some search i found, that i can use `SOAP/XML-RPC Request sampler` for this.
Since am not familiar with JMeter can any one help me out how to send the XML file using `SOAP/XML-RPC Request sampler`.

I already tested my application using normal `http request sampler`.

I used the following link for clarification and to understand the sampler:
[SOAP/XML-RPC Request sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SOAP/XML-RPC_Request).

Comment: Question is too vague, what did you try, what's your issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP Request Sampler is the best way to send xml.